# TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined announcement command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

When I run the command !announce it asks me for the title and I give a response. It is then supposed to respond with  : What do you want to say? but it remains blank and this is the error I get.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\Braden Dhillon\Desktop\bots\ultimatebot\commands\announce.js:22:12)
```

Discord JS V 11 btw.

Github code: https://github.com/LebryantJohnson/ultimatebot

Comment: could you post here the appropriate code segment? The `TypeError` you are receiving is bc you are trying to `access` a property on something `non-existing` in this case `announcement`.
Edit: `if(msg && msg.content && msg.content.toLowerCase() == "cancel") return message.channel.send(":x: **Canceled**");` You can avoid the error this way. Are you sure about the `ms.array()[0] ;` `array()` method call here? This is line `21` before `22`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that when you use `awaitMessages()` with a max of `1`, it returns a single `message` instead of a full `Collection`. Therefore, doing `const msg = ms.array()[0]` would not work since a `message` object does not have an `array()` method, and therefore `msg` would be undefined (hence why you cannot read property `content` of undefined).

You also need to account for what should happen if the user does not respond within 60 seconds. It should cancel in that instance as well.

Try changing the code in lines 20-22 of your [announce.js](https://github.com/LebryantJohnson/ultimatebot/blob/master/commands/announce.js#L20) to this:

```
const msg = await message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id === message.author.id, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] });
if(!msg || !msg.content || msg.content.toLowerCase() == "cancel") return message.channel.send(":x: **Canceled**");
```

It would also be helpful if, in future questions, you could directly add the relevant code snippet to your question or at the very least add a link like [this one](https://github.com/LebryantJohnson/ultimatebot/blob/master/commands/announce.js#L20) which leads directly to the lines we would need to look at.